# Why won't my WordPress functions.php load styles or scripts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom WordPress theme, I have done it once before. I looked at what I did for functions.php before and replicated it, changing the file names.

When I upload this theme, it uploads and does not give me an error about functions.php. When I check via the console, I see the files have not been loaded but there are no errors.

I have spent over 10 hours trying to do this, any help will be greatly appreciated! Also if anyone wants to look into this further including URL, let's connect!

```
<?php

/*LOAD SCRIPTS*/
function theme_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_min_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate_min_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blog_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/blog.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'calculators_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/calculators.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ionrangeSlider_min_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ionrangeSlider.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquerycookiebar_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquerycookiebar.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific-popup_min_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/magnific-popup.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'menu_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/menu.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owlcarousel_min_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owlcarousel.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owlthemedefault_min_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owlthemedefault.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'popup_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/popup.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');

/*REGISTERS SCRIPTS FOR IE*/
function theme_js(){

    global $wp_scripts;

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script('html5_shiv', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js', '', '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script('respond_js', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js', '', '', false );
    //false means do not load in footer but in the header like bootstrap

    $wp_scripts->add_data('html5_shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
    $wp_scripts->add_data('respond_js', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.js', array('jquery'), '', true );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_min_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery', 'bootstrap_min_js'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'commonscripts_min_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/commonscripts.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'validate_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/validate.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'functions_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), '', true );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-portfilter_min_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-portfilter.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryfitvids_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jqueryfitvids.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'videoheader_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/videoheader.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'vidinit_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vidinit.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wow_min_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was rather simple: I forgot to add a line of code in between the  tags in the header.php:

The Missing Code:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 4):

Also check the footer.php file to load js on footer

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```